# How can I convert a UNIX epoch timestamp into a Google Sheets date and time value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in which column L and M have a epoch timestamp. I want to convert it in readable date and time. I'm a beginner and here I have my code but is not working.

```
function timeToDate(string) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var d = sheet.getRange('L:L').getValue();
  var d = new Date(string*1000);
  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(d, tz, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a');

  return date;
}
```

Comment: Something like this `COLUMN_VALUE/ 86400 + DATE(1970, 1, 1)`

Comment: The code works fine for me. There is one redundant line `var d = sheet.getRange('L:L').getValue();` you can remove it, but it works anyway. https://imgur.com/bZayEed.png Probably you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you share your actual result and the expected result?

Comment: Is there any option to do it just through script?

Comment: Have you tired the suggested solution? This is a script.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. Have you run the function from the script to give it permissions tor run first?

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose this modification of the function:

```
function timeToDates(range) {
  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  try { range = range.flat().filter(String) } catch(e) { range = [range]}
  return range.map(t => 
    [Utilities.formatDate(new Date(t*1000), tz, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a')]);
}
```

[image]

Note: column the range 'B2:B' should be empty.